# passing parameters by GET php

Tags: php, url, get

I am writing a web app and at some point, I have a list of projects and when the user clicks on view on one of the projects I need to display the correct project page, basing on the project ID. (All the projects are stored in a Database). I am trying to pass the project id by a URL query string that should look like this

`user/project/view&proj_id=2`

then in my index.php, I try to var dump the `$_GET` but it says is an empty array while if I try to var dump the URI I get  `user/project/view&proj_id=2`

ho can I correctly pass and retrieve parameters with `$_GET`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `?` instead: `user/project/view?proj_id=2`